# Angular Material Date Picker selecting a start date from an injected service value

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular6, rxjs6

So I have a material DatePicker and form abbreviated in HTML like so:

```
<form novalidate (ngsubmit)="submit"
 [formGroup]="moneyForm">
    <mat-form-field>
       <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datePicker" 
          placeholder="Entry Date" 
          [formControl]="moneyForm.get('dateFormControl')">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
       <mat-datepicker #datePicker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
    {{startDate}} - {{endDate}}
</form>
```

And the component wire up abbreviated is like so:

```
startDate: Date = new Date();
endDate: Date = new Date();
moneyForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private transactionService: TransactionsService, 
          private fb: FormBuilder) { 
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.transactionService.getLastDate(1)
    .subscribe(x => this.startDate = x);

this.moneyForm = this.fb.group({
  dateFormControl: [this.startDate]
})
```

The problem is the timing appears to be delayed in getting the startDate till AFTER the the subscribe has obtained the observable date field.  Yes I observed the date is really getting obtained as the {{startDate}} in the HTML gets generated with it and I can use DevTools-Networking to see the call is successful as well.  If I change the code above my reactive form control to simply do a static assign like

```
this.startDate = new Date(2018, 5, 5);
```

It works right away and sets a default date in rendered content.  However another weird issue is that it sets the date one month forward like it's a zero based index of the months.  I just recently updated so I am pretty current using Angular 6.0.5 and Angular Material 6.3.0.  This problem did exist with Angular 6.0.0 and Angular Material 6.0 as well.

Really I just want to know if you can set up a pipe to map or similar so that the reactive control knows to not assign value till the subscribe is done.  I have tried extensions off of 'value' and 'valuechanged' to no avail.  Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I'm still a noob to Angular and event lifetimes in it.  I can do the assignment directly in the subscription of the 'getLastDate(1)'.  This unwraps my 'Observable' to a concrete object.  I can then set up my form group with this value which is then recognized fully at this time.  Like so:

```
this.transactionService.getLastDate(1)
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.startDate = x
        this.moneyForm.setValue({ dateFormControl: x })
      });
```